# SetForegroundWindow doesn't work with minimized process

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, minimized

Couldn't find any good answer on this topic, so maybe someone can help me out. I'm making a small personal program where I want to bring a certain application to the foreground. It already works, but there is one small problem. When the process is minimized my code doesn't work. The process won't get showed on the foreground like it does when it is not minimized.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p
            = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Client");

        if (p.Length > 0)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Window Not Found!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are going to need to call [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) before you try to set it as the foreground window.

Probably with `SW_RESTORE`:

```cs
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

 if (p.Length > 0)
 {
   ShowWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle, 9);
   SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
 }
```

[PInvoke.net - ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.showwindow) has some examples on `DllImport` and using the function in C#.